# What does (ry mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, internet-slang

I found this chapter title quite confusing:

> サブライターがメインに昇格した二作目って大抵（ry

which I understand to mean something like:

> A second work made by a sub writer who became the main writer? Seems mediocre.

I don't know what the `(ry` means though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is internet slang that is used to indicate that the rest of the sentence has been omitted for one reason or another, usually to some comedic effect. The answer is explained in detail on this site:

http://imimatome.com/netyogonoimi/ry.html

If the site is forbidden, try viewing a [cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:n0xoE2wkhp4J:imimatome.com/netyogonoimi/ry.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

> 最後までハッキリと言わない時に使う、謙虚なネット用語です（違
>   ハッキリ言わない方が面白いことがあったり、感情を表現できたりします。

This is basically as I said above: sometimes it's more humorous or effective not to say everything. It should be read as 略{りゃく}, and the "ry" comes from "ryaku."

Rather than venture to create my own examples, I'll borrow from the site again:

> A｢おい、聞いてくれ！昨日吉野家いったんです。
>   　そしたらなんか、家族連れで賑わってるんです。
>   　よくみたら（ry｣
>
> B｢さ、最後まで言えよっ！ｗ｣
>
> というような意味がわからない略の仕方をしたり、
>
> ｢それって結婚詐（ry｣と
>   明らかに略した言葉がわかる使い方をしたり、いろいろあります。

In your example, the person is suggesting that the second work by a secondary writer is usually a bit... yeah. You got the point I think. It's saying that the works aren't as good without saying that the works aren't as good, and it's using this little bit of slang to call attention to the act of omission.

A good English analogue might be [yada yada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6kRqnfsBEc).

Comment: Unfortunately, I seem to be blocked from that site. Japanese sites sigh...

Comment: @Ringil blocked? Are you in China or something? You should be able to glean the meaning from my post alone, but I'll try beefing up any parts that might be weak.

Comment: Nope, I'm in America. I'm getting 403 forbidden alas.

Comment: I don't know if they're filtering traffic or what, but the cached version seems to work. Try that.

Comment: Ah, google cache always coming in when the times are tough.

Comment: Here's another reference: http://zokugo-dict.com/01a/ry.htm

Comment: I usually use [here](http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok_ry.htm) or [here](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%28ry). But the latter one is more like Uncyclopedia...

Comment: @broccoliforest awesome sites, thanks. I just went with what Google gave me, but these seem good.

Comment: As a note, I'm also in America but have no trouble accessing it directly. @Ringil A 403 status code doesn't sound like traffic filtering though, it sounds more like there is an intermittent issue with the web server that's making the page inaccessible to the host process itself - not something we can fix.